# Which Ethereum clients support running a full node?

Tags: go-ethereum, parity, nodes

Are there any other Ethereum clients besides for Geth and Parity which support running a full node?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Harmony is a fully working full node implementation written in java (previously called ethereumj afaik) and cpp-ethereum is a full node implementation written in C++. There are several other implementations in the works. Trinity (previously py-evm, written in python) is "almost done" and is expected to be released soon. There'S at least one other in the works that I can't remember the name of.

Comment: Why does Harmony's Git repository call themselves 'Ethereum network private peer'? Why private?

Comment: I guess they were aiming at creating an implementation for private Ethereum networks: `gradlew runCustom -Dethereumj.conf.file=/path/to/custom.conf`